# In a multiple module maven project, how to completely rebuild all parent modules

Tags: maven

This might be a weird question. We have a complex multi-module maven project. Let's say we have two parent jobs: ParentJob1 and ParentJob2, ParentJob1 depends on ChildJobA, ChildJobB. ParentJob2 depends on ChildJobB and ChildJobC. ChildJobC depends on GrandChildJobX. Let's say a user changed ChildJobB, we would like to find all the jobs that depends on ChildJobB, in this case, ParentJob1 and ParentJob2 and then build all the jobs these jobs depends on, so in this case, basically everything. However, if a user changed ChildJobA, we would like to build ChildJobA and ParentJob1 only since that's the only jobs on the dependence tree.

Is there a way to so using the mvn compile command? Currently, we had to use mvn validate -pl ChildJobB -amd to find all the jobs depend on ChildJobB (and parse out the output, which is hardly reliable) and then mvn compile -pl ParentJob1,ParentJob2,ChildJobB -am to build all the dependencies. We are hoping to just pass ChildJobB to mvn compile to do this, but -am and -amd together only build parent jobs and child jobs (e.g. ParentJob1, ParentJob2 and ChildJobB in this case), not the other child jobs that the parent jobs might depends on. Unfortunately, we can't rely on the artifacts for the other child jobs to exists in the repo.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thx.

Comment: Please elaborate more in detail best with a structure of your projects and what you like to achieve..

Comment: I don't understand why you want that: I would either build everything, or the projects that directly or indirectly change (and that is `-am` and `-amd`). Those other projects you rebuild have not changed.

Comment: @JFMeier We can't build everything as it would produce a zip file about 200MB for each the parent jobs (we can have hundreds of them), which ends up blow our nexus repo pretty fast. Also due to the size, snapshot versions of the artifacts are deleted periodically (say every week), which means we can't rely on them being in the repo for very long. For example, let's say ChildJobC's artifact was deleted from the repo and we try to build ParentJob2 due to ChildJobB changed, the build would fail since we can't find a dependency.

Comment: @JFMeier In fact, now that I think of it, the best solution would be to have a way to say if a dependency is in the repo, download it, if not, build it.

Comment: @JFMeier @khmarbaise This is a good example: (https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html). Let's say both the nexus repo and the local repo has been deleted, if I do `mvn compile -pl sample-persist -amd -am`, it fails with the following error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sample-admin-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.sonatype.mavenbook.running:sample-admin-webapp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.sonatype.mavenbook.running:sample-security:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @wgemini Ok, now I understand your use case. I do not know any good solution for this.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://danielflower.github.io/multi-module-maven-release-plugin/index.html but this is only a vague idea.